# How to concatenate / append a JsonObject to a JsonArray

Tags: json, gson

Given the following code which gets called variously in the code, and then gets written to a file (separate method), I simple need to append the next value into the array.  This is probably a simple Collections question but wasn't sure if there was a specialized Gson way of doing this:

```
public static void metricAsJSON(String testName, long testTime) {

    Date date = new Date();
    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    obj.put("testname", testName);
    obj.put("Duration", testTime);
    obj.put("Timestamp", ts.toString());

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement je = jp.parse(obj.toJSONString());
    jsoncontent = gson.toJson(je);

    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    jsonArray.add(je);

    jsoncontent = gson.toJson(jsonArray);

}

public static JsonArray appendMetricAsJson(String jsoncontent){

    JsonArray jsonContentList = new JsonArray();
    jsonContentList.add(jsoncontent);        
    return jsonContentList;

    FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter(f1, true);

    PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(fw1);
    if (f1.exists() && f1.isFile()) {
        pw1.println(jsonContentList);
        pw1.flush();
        pw1.close();
        fw1.close();
    }
}
```

Current output:

```
[
  {
    "Duration": 30,
    "testname": "Shopping link click to dropdown display time:",
    "Timestamp": "2019-10-15 09:47:53.804"
  }
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
  {
    "Duration": 30,
    "testname": "Shopping link click to dropdown display time:",
    "Timestamp": "2019-10-15 09:45:13.334"
  },
  {
    "Duration": 16,
    "testname": "Clothing link click to dropdown display time",
   "Timestamp": "2019-10-15 09:44:34.356"
  },
  {
    "Duration": 24,
    "testname": "Toys link click to dropdown display time",
    "Timestamp": "2019-10-15 09:46:33.453"
  },
  {
    "Duration": 34,
    "testname": "Electrics link click to dropdown display time",
    "Timestamp": "2019-10-15 09:47:53.566"
  }
]
```

Comment: In your code, you're creating only one object and assigning it to `jsoncontent` variable. Where's the part where you want to append a new object to the existing one?

Comment: Yes, I am calling the method in several places and because I'm not collecting the data, I'm simply overwriting jsoncontent each time. So, I probably need to create a simple collection and then add the collection to the JsonArray-  just not having worked with Json in this way nor Gson, wondering how best to do it

Comment: You can create another method with a prefix like `appendMetricAsJson()` and in it you can append the new object to the existing `jsoncontent`.

Comment: thanks @Azeem , I'm just struggling to envisage what that looks like.  I've had a go and added such a method.  I'm just not used to massaging data into Json format using these libraries and getting the desired output seems challenging!

Comment: You're returning in the middle of the `append...` function. The rest of the statements are not reachable. There's are multiple Q&As on SO for that. Here's one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54574576/append-json-object-in-existing-json-file-using-java